# If positive, sum all items. If negative, return each one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am needing to find a way to `SUM()` all of the positive values for `num` and return the `SUM()` of all positive numbers and an individual row for each negative number.  Below is a sample DDL:

```
Create Table #Be
(
    id int
    , salesid int
    , num decimal(16,4)
)

Insert Into #BE Values
    (1, 1, 12.32), (2, 1, -13.00), (3, 1, 14.00)
    , (4, 2, 12.12), (5, 2, 14.00), (6, 2, 21.23)
    , (7, 3, -12.32), (8,3, -43.23), (9, 3, -2.32)
```

And this is my desired output (positive numbers for each salesid `SUM()` and negatives get an individual line returned):

```
salesid    num
1          26.32
1          -13.00
2          47.35
3          -12.32
3          -43.23
3          -2.32
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT   salesid, sum(num) as num
FROM     #BE
WHERE    num > 0
GROUP BY salesid
UNION ALL
SELECT   salesid, num
FROM     #BE
WHERE    num < 0;
```

If you want both the `sum` values in one row then you must create a `maxValue` (and `minValue`) function and use this as `sum(maxValue(0, num))` and `sum(minValue(0, num))`. This is described in: [Is there a Max function in SQL Server that takes two values like Math.Max in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne)

Answer (score 25):

This works too:

```
SELECT salesid, SUM(num)
FROM #BE
GROUP BY salesid, CASE WHEN num >= 0 THEN 0 ELSE id END;
```

Assumptions:

- Id starts at 1, hence it can use `THEN 0`. `salesid ELSE salesid+id+1` would work as well
- 0 is considered positive number, hence the `>= 0` ([Is zero positive or negative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/is-zero-positive-or-negative)). Although `x+0=x` seems to make the `=` sign unnecessary, it helps remember that this case has not been forgotten and how 0 is handled (as a SUM or as an individual row). If `the SUM() of all positive numbers` means `SUM of strictly positive numbers` (i.e. >0), then `=` is not needed.

It must be tested with real data and indexes, but with only 1 table scan, performances may be a little better in some cases.

The absence of an index seems to have a smaller impact with this query on test data below:

```
SET NO COUNT ON
Create Table #Be(
  id int identity(0,1)
  ,salesid int,num decimal(16,4)
)
INSERT INTO #BE(salesid, num) 
SELECT CAST(rand()*10 as int), rand() - rand()
GO 10000 -- or 100.000
```

Comment: You can simplify your group clause with an iif like this: `GROUP BY salesid, iif(num >= 0, 0, id)`  Cool query.

Comment: Yes but OP would have to first install SQL Server 2012. IIF starts with SQL Server 2012: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx. OP has tagged his question with SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT
  sum(profit) as pos_sum
FROM
  Sales
WHERE
  profit > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
  sum(profit) as neg_sum
FROM
  Sales
WHERE
  profit < 0;
```