# If at least a negative number, sum; otherwise just show

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, group-by, aggregate, window-functions

I have a need to sum values together only if there is a negative value present in a partition.  If there are no negative values in a partition, it should just output the row.

Here's what I have right now.  Initial data is provided as a CTE.

**DML**

```
;with ledger as (
    select accountId, type, amount
    from (
        values
         (1, 'R', -10)
        ,(1, 'V', 10)
        ,(1, 'R', 30)
        ,(2, 'R', 20)
        ,(2, 'R', -5)
        ,(2, 'V', 5)
        ,(3, 'R', 20)
        ,(3, 'R', 30)
    )   x (accountId, type, amount)
)
,b as ( --identifies accountid, type with negatives
    select
        accountid
        ,type               
    from ledger
    group by accountid, type
    having min(amount) < 0
)
,onlyPositives as (
    select
         l.accountid
        ,l.type
        ,l.amount
    from ledger l
    left join b on b.accountid = l.accountid
                and b.type = l.type
    where b.accountid is null
)
,aggregatedNegatives as (
    select 
         l.accountid
        ,l.type
        ,amount = sum(l.amount)
    from ledger l
    inner join b on b.accountid = l.accountid
                and b.type = l.type 
    group by l.accountid, l.type
)
select  accountid, type, amount
from    onlyPositives

union all

select  accountid, type, amount
from    aggregatedNegatives
```

I'm expecting an output like this, and the query above outputs correctly.

```
1, R, 20  (summed because -10+30=20)
1, V, 10  (left alone)
2, R, 15  (summed because 20-5=15)
2, V, 5   (left alone)
3, R, 20  (left alone)
3, R, 30  (left alone)
```

The query so far looks beastly and feels unnecessarily complex.  Is there a simpler query I could write that I have overlooked?

This is a slight variation on the issue: [If positive, sum all items. If negative, return each one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142552/if-positive-sum-all-items-if-negative-return-each-one)

rextester -> https://rextester.com/EZRT33825

Comment: Can you create an example on db fiddle?  I'm an Oracle guy but know how to simplify it with `analytics`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're after using window functions, but I can't make any promises about performance if you're running this query over a lot of rows. The idea is to calculate the sum, minimum, and an unordered row number for every partition. Keep all rows with a minimum > 0 but only keep the first row of a partition if the minimum < 0.

```
-- put data into temp table for illustration purposes
select accountId, type, amount into #t220618
from (
    values
     (1, 'R', -10)
    ,(1, 'R', 30)
    ,(1, 'V', 10)        
    ,(2, 'R', 20)
    ,(2, 'R', -5)
    ,(2, 'V', 5)
    ,(3, 'R', 20)
    ,(3, 'R', 30)
)   x (accountId, type, amount);


SELECT
  accountId
, type
, CASE WHEN part_min < 0 THEN part_sum else amount END amount
FROM (
    SELECT
      accountId
    , type
    , amount
    , SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, type) part_sum
    , MIN(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, type) part_min
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, type ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) part_rn
    FROM #t220618
) q
WHERE q.part_min > 0 OR (part_min < 0 AND part_rn = 1);
```